# I see no cube on startup. I can see that the cube is present as well as the camera and the lighting but it is not visible on the screen

Tags: 3d-view

I am using Blender 2.80 Beta. I have already tried switching the views from orthographic to perspective projections but to no avail.

Comment: go to File->Load Factory Settings.

Comment: It is still not visible.

Comment: It's still beta, wait till stable 2.8 is out.